# How to Synchronise Manipulates in Different Cells?

Tags: programming, dynamic, cdf-format

I need to have a few `Manipulate`s in different cells synchronize on a few variables.

I have a report with several `Manipulate`s in different sections showing different views/summaries of the data.  Some of the selection variables are common to all `Manipulate`s. When the reader updates one of these common in any of the `Manipulate`s I would like all `Manipulate`s to update the value of that variable and execute (or maybe execute on `"MouseMoved"` so the CDF doesn't crawl).

Using a Notebook level variable (I have `CellContext` set to `Notebook` in *Global Preferences*) I can see that the `sync` variable is syncing but I can't seem to get the `Manipulates` to use it.

```
sync = 1;

DynamicModule[{d = Range[10]},
 Manipulate[
  Column[{d[[;; j]], sync}],
  {{j, 1}, 1, 10, 1, 
   TrackingFunction -> {(j = sync) &, (j = #) &, (j = #; sync = #) &}}
  ],
 SaveDefinitions -> True
 ]

DynamicModule[{d = Range[10, 100, 10]},
 Manipulate[
  Column[{d[[;; i]], sync}],
  {{i, 1}, 1, 10, 1, 
   TrackingFunction -> {(i = sync) &, (i = #) &, (i = #; sync = #) &}}
  ],
 SaveDefinitions -> True
 ]
```

There is the new [Channel-Based Communication](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/Channel-BasedCommunication.html) in version 11 that might help but I don't have that installed yet (and it is experimental). I'll take an 10.4.1 or an 11 solution but I need it to work in CDF. Not certain there is Player Pro for version 11 yet.

Comment: @Kuba To move the `Slider` in a `Manipulate` and have that `Manipulate` update interactively. When the `Slider` is released the other `Manipulate`s should get the final value of `sync` from the `Manipulate` that was manipulated and then update themselves to that value of `sync`.

Comment: @Kuba The selected range of `d[[;; i]]` in the first and `d[[;; j]]` in the second does not update.  If I move the `Slider` in the first to $6$. Then I want the `d[[;; j]]` in the second to evaluate `d[[;; 6]]` when I release the `Slider`.  Likewise if I more the `Silder` in the second to $3$ then I want the `d[[;; i]]` in the first to evaluate `d[[;; 3]]` when I release the `Slider`.

Comment: @Kuba If I `d[[;; sync]]` then the Manipulate slider can't access it without localizing it and then it can't be used to sync across cells.

Comment: @Kuba That is not updating the `d[[;;i|j]]` with that `TrackingFunction`.

Comment: Any particular reason you need `Manipulate`?  I may be easier to work with `Slider` etc. directly.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard The `Manipulate`s are copy and pasted into the report with `SaveDefinitions`. Lots of code behind them and they are in different sections of the report.

Comment: DynamicModule has `SaveDefinitions` option too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another approach is to localize the context of the CDF and use `LocalizeVariables -> False` in `Manipulate`.  You have to remember to manually localize controls in the `Manipulate` that you don't want to share.

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], CellContext -> Notebook]

DynamicModule[{d = Range[10], offset},
 Manipulate[d[[;; j]] + offset,
  {{j, 1}, 1, 10, 1}, {offset, 0, 1},
  LocalizeVariables -> False],
 SaveDefinitions -> True]

DynamicModule[{d = Range[10, 100, 10], offset},
 Manipulate[d[[;; j]] + offset,
  {{j, 1}, 1, 10, 1}, {offset, 0, 1},
  LocalizeVariables -> False],
 SaveDefinitions -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I'm not sure which way will be too much trouble, maintaining the `TrackingFunctions` (e.g. Kuba's answers) or the scope of variables.  Someone on the site once said `Manipulate` is a beast (in part because it automatically rewrites your code, which is probably why the OP had trouble).  The typical advice here when things get complicated is to abandon `Manipulate` and do it all yourself with `DynamicModule[]`.

Comment: This is a good solution as well. I would have to place all my variables I wanted localized in the `DynamicModule` list. A little easier to maintain for a larger number of syncing variables. Also allows the syncing variable to be the same in all the `Manipulate`s. (+1)

Answer (score 5):

Since `j` and `i` have to be synchronized with `sync` one can add `j = sync;` and `i = sync;` at the beginning of parent `Manipulates` bodies:

```
DynamicModule[{d = Range[10]},
   Manipulate[
     j = sync; (*this is triggered when `sync` gets a values from the second M*)
     Column[{d[[;; j]], sync}], 
     {{j, 1}, 1, 10, 1, TrackingFunction -> ((j = sync = #) &)}
   ],
   SaveDefinitions -> True
]

DynamicModule[{d = Range[10, 100, 10]}, 
 Manipulate[
   i = sync; 
    Column[{d[[;; i]], sync}], 
    {{i, 1}, 1, 10, 1, TrackingFunction -> ((i = sync = #) &)}
 ], 
 SaveDefinitions -> True
]
```

Comment: This is works! I just have to tweak the `TrackingFunction` so `sync` only updates at the end of manipulating.  I'll wait a bit to see what else pops up; just in case. :-) (+1)

Comment: Sure, no hurry, I'm glad it fits your needs :)

Comment: I have decided to go with @MichaelE2 answer as it shares the synced variables across all `Manipulate`s and does not require `TrackingFunction`. I believe this approach will be easier to manage and maintain.