# Is there a way to apply Module and LocalizedVariables -> False simultaneously?

Tags: manipulate, scoping, variable

In my project, there are some variables that I want to define locally so that my defined function has no Manipulate dependency with each other when calling the function twice. By using `Module`, I am able to avoid this dependency by letting these variables be defined locally.

However, when evaluating the same function twice, it creates a new variable in the global setting due to `Module`. I have attempted to avoid this by defining the previous variable Globally after it is locally defined by implementing `LocalizeVariables->False` so that I can use this same variable every time I evaluate the same function.

Is there a happy medium where once a localized variable is defined, it can be used globally? Thank you!

EDIT: Here is a visually inaccurate (in terms of Manipulate visual placement) but working example to illustrate the issue that I am facing.

```
Testlistplot[{lis__}, {xmin_, xmax_, 
   sampint_, {xname_String, xunit_String}}] := ( 
  Module[{xInt, lists}, lists = {lis, {}};
   If[ValueQ[xInt] == False, xInt = {xmin, xmax};];
   Manipulate[Show[Table[ListLinePlot[lists[[k]], AxesLabel -> {xunit}, 
       DataRange -> {xmin, xmax}, PlotRange -> 
        If[ValueQ[xInt] == False, {{xmin, xmax}}, {xInt}]], {k, 1, 
       Length[lists]}]], {{xInt, {xmin, xmax}, Row[{xname}]}, xmin, 
     xmax, ControlType -> IntervalSlider, Appearance -> "Labeled", 
     Method -> "Stop", MinIntervalSize -> 0.001, 
     ImageSize -> {300, 25}}, ControlPlacement -> {Bottom}, 
    LocalizeVariables -> False]])
signal1 = Table[t^2, {t, 0, 3, 0.01}];
Testlistplot[{signal1}, {0, 3, 0.01, {"x-Axis", "seconds"}}]
```

Running the above code will store a Global variable defined as `xInt$####` and `lists$####` (`####` indicates a randomly chosen number). This is perfectly fine. However, re-evaluating the above code will produce a new set of Global variables defined as `xInt$&&&&` and `lists$&&&&` (`&&&&` indicates another randomly chosen number different than `####`). Is there some way to access `xInt$####` and `lists$####` after the first evaluation?

My inevitable goal is to try and distinguish "global variables" per cell. Therefore, every time when someone edits the cell, the "global variables" stored in that cell will be maintained. When someone inputs the same code in another cell, this will create a new set of "global variables" in that cell different than the ones previously defined. Thank you and sorry for the confusion!

Comment: I am not sure I completely understand your question. It might be that the function Unique can help you. It creates variables with a unique name during a Mathematica session, just as Module does.

Comment: I have added a working minimal example of my code to illustrate my problem. Thank you and sorry for the earlier confusion.

Comment: @Wilson For me to understand, let's say that you have in two different cells: `Module[{x}, x]`. At each new evaluation, independently of the cell, you will get a new `x$...` symbol. Do you want the evaluation in the first cell to always give the same `x$...`, and the same for the second cell with another `x$...`?

Comment: @Wilson For your first question, you can use `Echo` at the first occurence of `xInt` and `lists` within the module. So something like `Echo[xInt]` for instance. This will print the value of `xInt`. You could also use a global variable to store their values, so `xIntGlobal = xInt` would be written in the module, say right after the declaration of local variables. I'm not sure this is what you're after though.

Comment: @Xavier Your first comment is correct. I need this because I am trying to create a program for the engineering department and they require that some of the global variables are stored locally per cell. I will take a look at your `Echo` suggestion later today.

Comment: @Wilson You want to share some variables globally and keep some variables within the cell scope?  Is that correct?  If so see this post [123525](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/123525/).

Answer (score 2):

I'm having a hard time understanding what you are looking for. Your example code demonstrates the problem with giving the option `LocalizeVariables -> False` to `Manipulate`, but doesn't really tell me what would you would accept as a replacement. The best idea I can come up with is to memo-ize the current value of `{{xmin, xmax}` in a Notebook level tagging rule.

Start by initializing the tag.

```
CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], {TaggingRules, "testplot-x-span"}] = None;
```

To reestablish this initial value you will need to delete any running example of `Testplot` and re-evaluate the above code.

Now define the interactive tool.

```
Clear[Testplot]

Testplot[
    signals_: {__},
    {xmin_, xmax_, step_, {xname_String, xunit_String}}] :=
  DynamicModule[{initSpan},
    Manipulate[
      CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], {TaggingRules, "testplot-x-span"}] = xSpan;
      ListLinePlot[signals,
        AxesLabel -> {xunit, None},
        DataRange -> {xmin, xmax},
        PlotRange -> {xSpan, All}],
        {{xSpan, initSpan, xname}, xmin, xmax, step,
          ControlType -> IntervalSlider,
          Appearance -> "Labeled",
          Method -> "Stop",
          MinIntervalSize -> step,
          ImageSize -> {300, 25}},
           ControlPlacement -> Bottom],
    Initialization :> (
      initSpan =
        CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[], {TaggingRules, "testplot-x-span"}];
       If[initSpan === None, initSpan = {xmin, xmax}])]
```

With this definition `xmin` and `xmax` will be remembered even over re-evaluation of calls to `Testplot` and even re-evaluations of `Testplot` that don't change the memoization part of the code.

Now call `Testplot` with data to see how it looks

```
signal1 = Table[t, {t, 0, 4, 0.1}];
signal2 = Table[t^(1/2), {t, 0, 4, 0.1}];
Testplot[{signal1, signal2}, {0, 4, 0.1, {"x-Axis", "seconds"}}]
```

[image: init]

Now reduce the domain span.

[image: plot]

Now edit the control label (from "x-Axis" to "x-span") and re-evalute `Testplot`.

```
Testplot[{signal1, signal2}, {0, 4, 0.1, {"x-span", "seconds"}}]
```

[image: edited]

The label to the left of the interval slider has changed, but the reduced domain is remembered.